# change image onConfigurationChanged

Tags: android, user-interface

Is there a way to change ImageView drawable with its corresponding drawable for landscape mode without destroying the whole activity. I tried to set the drawable again in onConfigurationChanged callback but it doesn't work. Something like this

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration conf) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(conf);
    mImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.iv));
}
```

When i star the activity in landscape mode to correct drawable is displayed so resources are located correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your sample project just replace

```
iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.android);
```

with

```
iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.android));
```

I guess setBackgroundResource does nothing because the same resource is already assigned to ImageView.

Take a look at this
http://open-pim.com/tmp/ImageTest.zip
I tried your approach and it works just great for me.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but it's still not working for me. I suppose you forgot to declare android:configChanges="navigation|orientation" in your manifest and the activity is recreated. Here is my code (link to google docs) https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B6e5v3bLSI3ZYTQyYTRhYTctMDE4MS00M2QzLTk1Y2EtYWU3NmZmZmJiN2Zl&export=download&hl=en . When you start the activity is landscape mode or remove configChange from manifest everything is ok so the resources are located and loaded correctly.

Comment: android:configChanges is there, onConfigurationChanged is called. Please try my sample to ensure. I updated the link, it was incorrect.

Comment: setBackgroundResource is another possible issue

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to change ImageView
>   drawable with its corresponding
>   drawable for landscape mode without
>   destroying the whole activity.

When you change from portrait to landscape or vice versa the Activity is recreated. Check that the `onCreate()` method is called.

If you want to avoid this kind of behaviour use:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

for your `Activity` in the `AndroidManifest`.

--

In relation to your question:
I first would check what it's called first after an orientation change:
`onConfigurationChanged` or `onCreate`.

If `onConfigurationChanged` is called first, then your `setContentView()` in your `onCreate()` method is replacing your `ImageView` drawable.

Comment: As i posted i don't want to recreate the activity after configuration changed. Yes i used android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" in manifest file so my activity is created only once and then with every configuration change onCongigurationChanged is called without recreating the activity and my goal is to change some ImageView underlying drawable with the drawable placed in res/drawable-land.

Comment: The OP wants to handle the orientation change by his code(to avoid app recreate), and he needs access to the resources for landscape orientation.

Comment: @Mojo Risin: oh, ok. So `onConfigurationChanged` is called although you have setted that in your Manifest?

Comment: If you don't set it in manifest android won't call it. According to documentation onConfigurationChanged is called only for configurations that are set in android:configChanges clause for the rest the activity is just recreated.

Answer (score 0):

For the emulator, you'll need screenLayout in addition to orientation to call the method.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout"
```